# Is vector math node slower than math node?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes, optimization

I looked at https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/optimizations/nodes.html#node-optimizations and apparently Blender is pretty good at optimizing node trees.

This made me wonder a have a node group that uses vector math nodes. In one part in the tree it is fed input vectors, while in another part it is fed input float values. Preferably I want to use the same node tree twice, however I am not sure if Blender is smart enough to convert the vector math nodes to regular math nodes at render time.

Can someone please help here?

Comment: There will probably be a tiny difference here. If you are very precise, the calculation with one float value is always faster than with three.

Comment: Are you sure that's the case? Because Blener may be smart enough to notice that it's doing the same calculation three times and simply merge them into one.

Comment: Well, not quite sure, but a vector math node would then have to at least check if all three inputs have the same value....

Comment: But still: To me it looks like the calculation for Vector-Math is passed directly to the shader without checking if all three float values are equal. [Source 1](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/nodes/shader/nodes/node_shader_vector_math.cc#L77) [Source 2](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/gpu/shaders/material/gpu_shader_material_vector_math.glsl)

Comment: Huh, looks like a possible optimization for me.

Comment: @tempdevnova A single vec3 multiplication is basically free. Blender is actively doing raytracing, lighting calculations / GGX, subsurface scattering, all of these are vastly more complicated.

To be precise, and less hand-wavy, an Intel HD Integrated Graphics card does ~400 GFLOPS. So, 1920x1080 resolution gives 185,000 FLOPS / pixel / second. Wasting 2FLOPS per pixel per frame will cost you ~6 microseconds per frame.

In reality, if at any point there's a bottleneck anywhere else (CPU, CPU->GPU, GPU texture fetching), the actual negative impact will be less than 6 microseconds per frame.